# debugger option in visual studio 2005

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005

I am developing a asp.net website and need to add validator for multiple textboxes. I googled it and found a custom validator.

I add this as a project and do things.. and the website is running fine.

But whenever I run the project with Start Debugging icon, the following message appears.
[image]

I can click OK and continue but this has become really annoying.. Any idea not to appear this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you at the bottom of the dialog how to turn off the warning:

> To suppress this message, disable the 'Warn if no user code on launch' debugger option.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I have been trying to get that debugger option. I dunno where to find.. Pls HELP..

Comment: You need debug symbols, or source code - both supplied by the person who made the Validator DLL

Comment: Try Tools -> Options -> Debugging/General -> Enable Just My Code (Managed Only) -> Warn if no user code on launch.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Just My Code > Warn if no user code on launch

[image]

Comment: by why? What is the reason behind this `message`?

Comment: they're trying to pre-emptively tell you that the error messages are going to suck and that you can't step through code that you might otherwise expect to step through